# creating a table on postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Hello I blocked in the creation of a simple table please help me 
using ubuntu 11.04 -  PostgreSQL 8.4.8 
with phppgadmin I get this code :

```
CREATE TABLE users 
(
  id                SERIAL,
  username          CHARACTER VARYING(255),
  PASSWORD           CHARACTER VARYING(255),
  etat              INTEGER(1),
  avatar            CHARACTER VARYING(255),
  description       text,
  email             CHARACTER VARYING(255),
  website           CHARACTER VARYING(255),
  country           CHARACTER VARYING(255),
  location          CHARACTER VARYING(255),
  nb_upload         INTEGER,
  sexe              CHARACTER VARYING(25),
  group_id          INTEGER,
  created           DATE,
  modified          DATE,
  enable_mail       INTEGER(1),
  enable_location   INTEGER(1),
  facebook_id       BIGINT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

but every time I execute , it return this error :

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
>   LINE 1: ... "password" character varying(255), "etat" integer(1), "avat...

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it's a great idea to be mixing different languages in an app, but I suppose it's your problem in the long run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`integer(1)` is not a valid data type in PostgreSQL. The correct name is `integer`

See the manual for a complete list of all available types:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html

Edit:

If you want to store a "flag" that stores true/false use the `boolean` data type instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."users" ("id" SERIAL, "username" character varying(255), "password" character varying(255), "etat" integer, "avatar" character varying(255), "description" text, "email" character varying(255), "website" character varying(255), "country" character varying(255), "location" character varying(255), "nb_upload" integer, "sexe" character varying(25), "group_id" integer, "created" date, "modified" date, "enable_mail" integer, "enable_location" integer, "facebook_id" bigint, PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
```

this should work for you) by the way what do you mean by integer(1) ?)